# what is an illegal VPN address with vpnservices

Tags: android, android-vpn-service

I have an IllegalArgumentException because of the vpn address I use with vpn services. In fact I use the same IP address that is set on my device either by 3G/4G or wifi.

What are the rules for legal address? When is an address illegal?

On my htc phone (6.0) and samsung tablet (4.4) it is just working fine.

The crash happens on a samsung on5 running 6.0 and is on the line builder.addAddress:

```
    builder.addAddress(VPN_ADDRESS, 32);
    builder.addRoute(VPN_ROUTE, 0);
    vpnInterface = builder.establish();
```

Comment: you are supposed to decide the illegal address

Comment: so using the same ip as what is given by the network is legal?

Comment: i mean, throw the exception for ips you want to block